# Код не проходит лимит по времени (оптимизация на python)

Tags: python

Я решала задачу:

> Вам даны *n* целых чисел *a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, …,
> a<sub>n</sub>*.
>
> Найдите максимальное значение *max(a<sub>l</sub>, a<sub>l+1</sub>, …, a<sub>r</sub>)·min(a<sub>l</sub>, a<sub>l+1</sub>, …, a<sub>r</sub>*) по всем парам *(l, r)* целых чисел, для которых *1 ≤ l < r ≤ n*.
>
> ### Входные данные
>
> Первая строка содержит одно целое число *t* (*1 ≤ t ≤ 10000*)  —
> количество наборов входных данных.
>
> Первая строка каждого набора входных данных содержит одно целое число
> *n* (*2 ≤ n ≤ 10<sup>5</sup>*).
>
> Вторая строка каждого набора входных данных содержит *n* целых чисел
> *a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, …, a<sub>n</sub>* (*1 ≤ a<sub>i</sub> ≤ 10<sup>6</sup>*).
>
> Гарантируется, что сумма *n* по всем наборам входных данных не
> превышает *3·10<sup>5</sup>*.
>
> ### Выходные данные
>
> Для каждого набора входных данных выведите одно целое число —
> максимально возможное значение произведения из условия.
>
> ### Пример
>
> входные данные
>
> ```
> 4
> 3
> 2 4 3
> 4
> 3 2 3 1
> 2
> 69 69
> 6
> 719313 273225 402638 473783 804745 323328
> ```
>
> выходные данные
>
> ```
> 12
> 6
> 4761
> 381274500335
> ```

Написала по ней код:

```
n=int(input()) 
for x in range(n):
    m=int(input()) 
    a=list(map(int, input().split())) 
    ans=a[0]*a[1] 
    for l in range(m-1):
        for r in range(l+1, m):
            s=a[l:r+1] 
            if min(s)*max(s)>ans:
                ans=min(s)*max(s)
    print(ans)
```

Но он не проходит лимит по времени, подскажите пожалуйста, как его можно ускорить!!!

Comment: Посмотрите какие пары *l, r* находит ваша программа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рассмотрим произведение на отрезке *(l, r)*:

> ```
>     *
>   *           *
> *       *
>       *     *
>           *
> ---------------
> l . m . . . . r
> ```

Пусть *m* - позиция максимума в этом отрезке. Рассмотрим отрезок *(m, m + 1)* если *m < r* и *(m - 1, m)* иначе. Для определённости пусть будет *(m, m + 1)*.

Максимумы у *(l, r)* и *(m, m + 1)* одинаковы. Минимум у *(m, m + 1)* больше или равен минимуму *(l, r)*. Следовательно и произведение для *(m, m + 1)* не меньше произведения *(l, r)*.

То есть для любого длинного отрезка *(l, r)* предъявлен короткий отрезок *(m, m + 1)* с таким же или большим произведением. Рассматривать длинные отрезки не надо, максимальное произведение получится на отрезке длины два.

Таких отрезков линейное количество, значит и сложность программы тоже будет линейная. Сейчас сложность вашей программы кубическая. Для *n = 10<sup>5</sup>* ваша программа сделает порядка *10<sup>15</sup>* операций. Линейная программа сделает порядка *10<sup>5</sup>*.  Ускорение в *10<sup>10</sup>* раз.

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    input() # skip n
    a = tuple(map(int, input().split())) 
    print(max(max(al, ar) * min(al, ar) for al, ar in zip(a, a[1:])))
```

> ```
> $ cat input.txt
> 4
> 3
> 2 4 3
> 4
> 3 2 3 1
> 2
> 69 69
> 6
> 719313 273225 402638 473783 804745 323328
>
> $ python max-min.py < input.txt
> 12
> 6
> 4761
> 381274500335
> ```